# Facebook Link Keeps Going to Home Page

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-activity

I'm running the following and expecting it to go to the link using the Facebook app but instead it keeps opening and remaining on the Homepage/Wall. Works fine when the link is https:// rather than fb:// but of course then it uses the internet explorer rather than the app. Am I missing something?

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://www.facebook.com/<user_name>")));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fb://profile/<id_here>
```

this should help

Comment: Ah, indeed! Kudos. Emphasis on the <id> part versus the <user_name> too.